# In attempting to combine two arays I have a type problem in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I attempt:

```
data_f = hstack([data,Ki])
```

I get:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

I have 'googled' in vain without result. What have I missed?

I have successfully created the two arrays I want to combine:

```
data = []
data = np.vstack([data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data10])

A = []
A = data[:,1]

Ki = []
Ki = np.exp((1000*A)/(Rcal*Tk))

name_s = name+'_Ki'
np.savetxt(name_s,[A],newline='\n',delimiter = ' ')

data_f = []

hstack = []
data_f = hstack([data,Ki])
```

Comment: A function is `callable`, and `called` with `()`, as you do with `hstack(...)`.  But you define `hstack=[]`, a list.

Comment: All of those `x=[]` statements are unnecessary in Python.  Use that only if you go onto modify `x`, as with `x.append('foobar')`.  In Python variables don't need to be 'initialed'.  Just assign real, useful objects, as with your `data=np.vstack(...)`.  Why did you use `np.vstack` but not `np.hstack`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used vstack  to create the data structure successfully.  The problem is with the use of hstack (the last line is the code fragment above.)

Comment: I changed the last line to read data_f = np.hstack([data,K1]).  Now the error is 'ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions'.

Comment: So what are the dimensions of the 2 inputs, `data` and `K1`?  The first to do when you get errors about dimensions and shape is to check (print out) the shape of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Please [Read The Fine Manual](https://numpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack),
where they clearly explain that `hstack()` wants
a tuple of ndarrays of similar shape.
You're not supplying that.

Carefully examine `data` & `Ki`,
to ensure they have similar `.shape`

EDIT

Here is an example of calling `hstack()`:

```
>>> a = np.array(range(3)).reshape(3, 1)
>>> b = np.array(range(12)).reshape(3, 4)
>>> a.shape, b.shape
((3, 1), (3, 4))
>>> np.hstack((a, b))
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Notice that making `a` just `np.array(range(3))` would not work.
To understand why, look at the difference between the `.shape`
of those expressions.

Comment: Thank your for your erudite explanation. My original question stated that data is a float64 array with dimensions of (100,40 and that Ki is float64 array with dimensions (100,1). Perhaps in my 80 years of reading I didn't understand what the reference is saying. I really don't see what the solution to the problem might be.

Comment: Perhaps there's some text on your local C: drive that says that, but I can't read it. Certainly you weren't stating that in your question.

Comment: Well, that was a red faced forehead slapper! Column-stack solved the problem, thanks to numpy-user-1.19.1.pdf.